# Unhandled Exception when using url launcher in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, url-launcher

```
RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
      children: [
        TextSpan(
          text: "Soumik's LinkedIn Profile",
          style:
              TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.blue),
          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
            ..onTap = () async {
              var url =
                  "https://www.linkedin.com/in/soumik-mukherjee-438b451b5/";
              if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                await launch(url);
              } else {
                throw "Failed to open LinkedIn";
              }
            },
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

I wrote this code on flutter to launch the URL of my LinkedIn profile. When I run this on an emulator, it works fine as the webpage opens automatically when I tap on the URL. But, when I tried the same on a physical device by running the app in debug mode, the URL does not respond. Instead, I get an error in the console.

[image: THIS IS THE SCREENSHOT OF THE ERROR IN THE TERMINAL]

Comment: Can you specify which device you are trying to use?

Comment: @PlutoHDDev I am using POCO X2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have Android 11 installed on your POCO X2, which is API level 30.

Here is the documentation for the `canLaunch` function: https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/canLaunch.html.

The documentation says: "On Android (from API 30), canLaunch will return false when the required visibility configuration is not provided in the AndroidManifest.xml file. For more information see the [Managing package visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility) article in the Android docs."

Therefore I assume that you did not provide the visibility configuration in the AndroidManifest.xml file which causes `canLaunch` to return `false`.

Comment: I have tried but the problem remains the same. It's also possible that I may have made some mistake. It would be nice if you elaborate the process. I followed what was stated in the blog and the documentation but didn't work.

Comment: Before I try to elaborate what to do, I recommend that you have a look at this: [https://medium.com/flutter-community/package-visibility-for-url-launcher-on-android-11-api-30-7c03cbce76a5](https://medium.com/flutter-community/package-visibility-for-url-launcher-on-android-11-api-30-7c03cbce76a5). Make sure to read the edit of the article on the bottom of it.

Comment: Yup thnx a lot. It really helped a lot. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Was it possible to solve the problem with this answer? Perhaps it would be helpful for others to then mark this answer as such.